# Hanging indentation of text inline with the equation in align environment

Tags: align

I wish to have my inline text (not intertext) have a hanging indentation. I could not achieve that and below is the picture showing my problem:
[image]
Below is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{align*}
        \mathbb{E}[S]&=\mathbb{E}[N]\mathbb{E}[X]\quad{\substack{\text{\normalsize(for a detailed derivation of this simplified formula, see Question \textbf{A2}}\\  \text{\normalsize   above.)}}}\\
        &=  \left[ \frac{(1-p)}{p}\right] \underbrace{\left[ \frac{\lambda}{\alpha-1}\right]}\\
        \intertext{Also,}
        \mathbb{V}[S]&=\mathbb{E}[N]\mathbb{V}[X]+\mathbb{V}[N]\left\lbrace \mathbb{E}[X] \right\rbrace^{2}\quad{\substack{\text{\normalsize(for a detailed derivation of this simplified formula,}\\  \text{\normalsize see Question \textbf{A2} above.)}}}\\
        &=\left[ \frac{(1-p)}{p} \right] \left[ \frac{\alpha\lambda^{2}}{(\alpha-1)^{2}(\alpha-2)}\right] + \left[ \frac{(1-p)}{p^{2}} \right]\left[ \frac{\lambda^{2}}{(\alpha-1)^{2}}\right]  
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: substack is for centred math just use `\parbox[t]{3cm}{(for a detailed derivation o....`

Comment: I might load the `\linegoal` package and do something `\parbox[t]{\linegoal}{\hangindent=3em\hangafter=1(for a...` (or define a command for that). (You might also put that inside `\smash` if you never wanted it to introduce more vertical space.) It'll take multiple compilations to get right.

Comment: How do I force a line break using parbox?

Comment: Simply use   `\\` within the \parbox